# Google Chrome hover toward tab causes Mac's menu bar at top of screen to come down

Tags: google-chrome

When I want to click a specific chrome tab in full screen, if I accidentally hover too high and hit the top of the screen the mac menu bar comes down.

Is there a way to disable to menu bar from coming down in this scenario? Or maybe a way to make it less sensitive.

Comment: Questions about browser functions are on topic on [su]. Questions about Apple hardware or software are on topic on [Apple.se]. I think this is likely best answered on the latter.